# Disabling access via HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

I currently have a website that allows users to create profiles and add their own custom domains, effectively masking their domains.

I've just enabled HTTPS on my main domain and now when I'm accessing their full domains (theirdomain.com) through HTTPS, it says: `The identity of this website has not been verified. Server's certificate does not match the URL.`

When checking to see if HTTPS is on `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` it doesn't show that HTTP is on, which is correct because HTTPS isn't working--although the URL has been accessed through HTTPS.

Is it possible to just redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP for every domain but my own `(maindomain.com)`

Either via PHP or HTACCESS, or through Apache?

Comment: _“which is correct because HTTPS isn't working--although the URL has been accessed through HTTPS”_ – those two statements are mutually exclusive. Either you accessed something via HTTPS, which would mean it _is_ working – or you didn’t; both at the same time is nonsense. And you can of course not redirect a request if it does not even _reach_ your server because the client aborts it half-way because of the certificate not matching the host name.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to just redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP for every domain but my own

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
RewriteEngine On
%{HTTPS} on
%{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?maindomain\.com
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `302` to `301` to make it permanent.
This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: @Cbroe, your points are well taken but did you downvote this? It's a precise answer to `Is it possible to just redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP for every domain but my own`

Comment: It definitely deserves a +1 for precisely answering OP's problem.